# How to retrieve files located within http subfolders using wget

Tags: unix, wget

I'm trying to retrieve some files from e.g. http://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/MERIS/L3BIN/2010/. Within that location there are sub-folders corresponding to days. Every 8 days, there is a file with a name containing the string *L3b_8D_CHL.main.bz2, which I would like to download. (e.g. one full path is: "http://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/MERIS/L3BIN/2012/001/M20100012010008.L3b_8D_CHL.main.bz2").

For a single file, I can download in the following way:

```
wget -q -O - http://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/MERIS/L3BIN/2012/001/ |grep 8D_CHL|wget -N --wait=0.5 --random-wait --force-html -i -
```

Is there a way that I could cycle through all of the folders in http://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/MERIS/L3BIN/2012/ and look for files that matched the "8D_CHL" pattern, and then download them?

Comment: See these two related posts: http://superuser.com/questions/600213/mirror-website-with-wget-but-only-matching-url-pattern http://superuser.com/questions/487205/wget-recursive-limited-within-subdomain

Answer (score 0):

HTTP doesn't really have a concept of subfolders, although that page does look like they are, it's still returning a HTML page full of tags and links that you would need to parse.

But, because the files are so predictably named, I would be tempted to ignore the HTML and just guess where the files are going to be.

They are named:

```
2010/001/M20100012010008.L3b_8D_CHL.main.bz2
2010/009/M20100092010016.L3b_8D_CHL.main.bz2

Which is

2010/001/M{year}{day}{year}{day+7}.L3b_8D_CHL.main.bz2
```

So I would go for guessing the download links:

```
#!/bin/bash
for year in `seq 2002 2012`; do
    for day in `seq -w 1 8 365`;
    do
        echo wget http://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi/getfile/M$year$day$year$(printf "%03d" `expr $day + 7`).L3b_8D_CHL.main.bz2
    done
done
```

Sample output:

```
wget http://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi/getfile/M20122572012264.L3b_8D_CHL.main.bz2
wget http://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi/getfile/M20122652012272.L3b_8D_CHL.main.bz2
wget http://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi/getfile/M20122732012280.L3b_8D_CHL.main.bz2
```

NB. Except for the last one in the year which is day 361 to day 365, you'll have to get that another way.